# Inserir botão de cadastro

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Quero colocar um botão de cadastro bem como esta na imagem abaixo. Tem como eu deixar desse jeito utilizando css/bootstrap?

[image: Campo de login]

Eu estou utilizando este código:[Código página de login/cadastro](https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd)

É que estou tentando fazer ele ficar responsivo, tipo, quando vai para a resolução do celular eu quero deixa ele com a aparência como da foto, e ao clicar no botão de cadastro vai fazer a transição de tela para página de cadastro.

**Código CSS modificado:**

```
    @media (max-width: 699px){

    h1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        margin: 20px 0 30px;
    }

    a {
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        
    }

    button {

        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #00a65a;
        background-color: #00a65a;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 12px 45px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
        
    }

    button:active {
        transform: scale(0.95);
    }

    button:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    button.ghost {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    form {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 20px;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    input {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: none;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        margin: 6px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
                0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 350px;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
    }

    .form-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }

    .sign-in-container {
        left: 0;
        width: 90%;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .sign-up-container {
        left: 0;
        width: 90%;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
        animation: show 0.6s;
    }

    @keyframes show {
        0%, 49.99% {
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        50%, 100% {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 5;
        }
    }

    .overlay-container {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 90%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    .overlay {
        background: #FF416C;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #09CE03, #00a65a);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #09CE03, #00a65a);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 0 0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        position: relative;
        left: -100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 200%;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }

    .container.right-panel-active .overlay {
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    
    .overlay-panel{
        display: none;
    }
    .overlay-left{
        display: none;
    }
    .overlay-right{
        display: none;
    }

    .overlay-cell {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 40px;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }

    .overlay-leftcell {
        transform: translateX(-20%);
    }

    .container.right-panel-active .overlay-leftcell {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    .overlay-rightcell {
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    .container.right-panel-active .overlay-rightcell {
        transform: translateX(20%);
    }
    .social-container {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .social-container a {
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 5px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: .btn{
      display:inline-block;  
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;

    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    }

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Cadastro</button>

Comment: @Exius adicione mais informações à sua e pergunta. Inclua o que você já fez até agora e não deu certo, e como você espera seja a implementação. Por exemplo, trecho do seu código html e css, quais classes do bootstrap você já usou. etc.

Comment: acrescentei algumas informações

Comment: Resolvi remover os efeitos de transição e deixar um formulário abaixo do outro ao alterar a resolução abaixo de 720px